# Method to specify the Solidify thickness based on another surface

Tags: modifiers

I have a set of concentric spheres of varying radii, each a different color (material). I would like to use the SOLIDIFY modifier, and add a thickness to each such that it fills in the distance between the larger sphere and the smaller sphere.

I plan to put this in a script, so I have tried to build an algorithm based on their radii (and the difference of), but something's not working out. A visual example may help. Below is a 1-D model from the outside of the largest sphere (left) the center of the concentric spheres "(center)":

Crrnt:
1.......2...3......4.....5......(center)

Ideal:
1111111 2222 3333333 444444 5555555 (center)

Answer (score 1):

You could add a driver to the Thickness value.

[image]

In this example, I've used the property **dimension.x** (it corresponds to the diameter).

If you need the value to change only at certain steps, you can set the interpolation mode to **constant**:
[image]

When you duplicate the sphere (<kbd>alt</kbd> +<kbd>d</kbd>), the driver will automatically update and it will mantain the reference to the proper diameter.

**NOTE:**
Remember to apply the scale transformation after scaling, otherwise the Thickness value will scale too.

Answer (score 0):

**Question:**
   I am trying to pre-determine the Thickness property of the Solidify modifier required to completely fill the gap between two concentric, spherical shells. I know the diameter of both shells ahead of time, the shells will always be centered at (0,0,0). I would like to keep Offset = -1.0.
   Using a number of examples, I have tried to back out a mathematical relationship / equation, based on the difference in the diameter of the shells.  But this falls apart when the shells diameters change, but the difference between the shell diameters remains the same.

*Example:*
    If i have a hemisphere of diameter1 = 8m, and a smaller, concentric shell with diameter1 = 2m (difference = 6m), then a Thickness value of 0.7485 will fill the gap between these two hemispherical shells.
   However, if I use 2 shells that are diam1 = 100m, and diam2 = 94m (difference = 6m), then a Thickness value of 0.05975 fills in the gap between the concentric shells.

How can I pre-determine what this thickness needs to be for any case of 2 concentric shells?

**Response:**
Not my solution, but from one of the Blender experts:

"I'm quite sure the thickness parameter gives a direct offset from the
surface, i.e. a perfect sphere with radius R and solidify thickness X
creates a sphere with radius (R+X). This matches the first observation,
where dR=3 => thickness = 1.5 / 2 = 0.75 ~= 0.7485. The reason you don't
see these values in the second case is probably because the object is
scaled by 100/8 = 12.5 => thickness = 0.75 / 12.5 = 0.06"

Answer (score 0):

The thickness value is exactly half the difference of the diameters:

```
(Dmax-Dmin) / 2
```

[image]

Remember to apply the scale transformation (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>) if you are scaling the sphere, otherwise the Thickness value will scale too.